# All the ways you can describe a relationship outside of nouns/verbs/adjectives across languages (i.e. like with prepositions)?

Tags: grammar, words, prepositions, function

Having dug more into prepositions, I learned they are often "[function words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_word)" (as opposed to "lexical words", i.e. "content words"). However, in at least one paper I read (don't remember the title), it said prepositions are very hard to define, and often are on a spectrum of being partially function words and partially lexical words. Another paper I saw, *[Word Order in Mandarin: Reading and Speaking](https://naccl.osu.edu/sites/naccl.osu.edu/files/37_gao-q.pdf)*, said prepositions must satisfy 3 properties:

> [Gao] argues that a
> preposition must have at least **three major linguistic properties**. **First**, as a lexical head, **it
> should have a full semantic or grammatical content of its own**. For instance, in English,
> the meaning of the preposition on in the phrase on the table is the space on or above the
> table. This is seen from its grammatical function of mapping the NP to the space above it.
> **Second**, **it must be able to combine with another phrase to form a (different) phrase with
> it as the head**. That is, it should be able to change the syntactic category of the phrase it
> combines with. For instance, in English, the preposition on, when combined with the NP
> the table, changes the NP to a PP on the table. **Third**, since the preposition is the head of
> a PP, **it should be the obligatory element of the phrase**. That is, its existence should be
> independent of the element it combines with or any other element in the sentence. In
> English, this property can be seen from the fact that prepositions generally are allowed to
> be stranded.

So, people are varied on their opinions as to what at least "preposition" means (or more generally, "adposition").

Now, function words are typically closed class words, and serve a "grammatical role" in relating elements of the sentence. Prepositions are these, but they may also have additional semantic meaning.

Like the words **on** or **in**. When I visualize these "spatial relationship" words, I visualize as a sort of hand-wavy *animation*, moving from one place to another (a before and after, sort of). Same with "through", you can imagine like going through a bunch of tall grass or something.

So I'm wondering, across languages, what are the different ways you can have these pseudo-functional pseudo-lexical words which describe these sorts of visualizable relationships (outside of nouns/verbs/adjectives, i.e. the easy "open class" words)? Is it *always done* through adpositional words? Or are there other approaches? If so, could you paint a quick picture of the spectrum of how these sorts of grammatical/functional + content "concepts" could be mapped to word(s) or sorts? What are the possibilities?

I am trying to use this as an exercise to think outside the box. How have other cultures and languages (mainly natural languages) imagined or encoded these relationships into concise words or phrases? So I can begin to see what is possible in terms of how the mind works.

Answer (score 2):

Any request for "all the ways any relation can be expressed" is, IMO, an unfillable order. We could narrow it down a bit.

In English we have a preposition "from" that conveys [insert mental image indicating 'origin']. Japanese instead has a postposition *kara*. Finnish has a case suffix (elative) *-sta* which does a similar job, likewise Quechua *-manda*. In various Bantu languages there is a verb "to come from" pressed into service, for instance Shona *ndakatora gari **kubva** Harare* 'I took the car from Harare', similarly *kutoka* in Swahili. However in Zulu, you would use a general locative prefix *e-*. I don't know of a Bantu language that does this with a verbal suffix for "from", but goal locatives ('he threw it into the house') are often expressed with the verbal 'applied' suffix -il- which also conveys benefactive / malefactive relations.

At this point, I would conclude that you can in principle express the "from" relation pretty much any reasonable way you can express anything. You don't find languages where you express X by saying X four times, using high pitch and breathy voice, but you do find breathy voice as a grammatical marker, also tone, and reduplication.

Answer (score 1):

Some more information specifically about Japanese.

All case particles in Japanese are postpositional (placed after nouns).

---

Only for very few types of relations, there exist case particles, which by themselves can express specifically these relations. Examples:

- *NOUN の(no)* = "of NOUN" (not to be mistaken with speculatively historically related homonymous copula *の(no)*)
- *PLACE に(ni)* = "in PLACE" (used with states, e.g. "to exist", "to live")
- *PLACE で(de)* = "in PLACE" (used with actions, e.g. "to do") (not to be mistaken with historically related homonymous form *で(de)* of copula)
- *PLACE から(kara)* = "from PLACE"
- *PLACE に(ni)* = "to, towards PLACE"
- *PLACE へ(he)(pronounced [e̞])* = "to, towards PLACE"

---

For many other types of relations, combinations of nouns with particle に(ni) or で(de) (depending on verb) are used. Examples:

- *中(なか/naka)* is noun meaning "the inside"

  *NOUN の(no) 中(なか/naka) に(ni)* = lit. "in the inside of NOUN" = "inside NOUN"
- *上(うえ/ue)* is noun meaning "the above"

  *NOUN の(no) 上(うえ/ue) に(ni)* = lit. "in the above of NOUN" = "above NOUN"
- *下(した/sita)* is noun meaning "the below"

  *NOUN の(no) 下(した/sita) に(ni)* = lit. "in the below of NOUN" = "below NOUN"
- *前(まえ/mae)* is noun meaning "the front, the before"

  *NOUN の(no) 前(まえ/mae) に(ni)* = lit. "in the front of NOUN" = "in front of NOUN"
- *後ろ(うしろ/usiro)* is noun meaning "the behind, the back"

  *NOUN の(no) 後ろ(うしろ/usiro) に(ni)* = lit. "in the behind of NOUN" = "behind NOUN"
- *そば(soba)* is noun meaning "the near, vicinity"

  *NOUN の(no) そば(soba) に(ni)* = lit. "in the near of NOUN" = "near NOUN"

I would personally describe such nouns as auxiliary nouns.